# How to login as user rather bot in discord server and run commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Slack API provides you two options: use app as a bot and as a *logged in* user itself. I want to create App that will be working as a user and run channel commands. How can I do with `discord.py`?

Comment: Via a selfbot where you use your user token

Comment: @ADug can you elaborate it?

Comment: A selfbot is against Discord ToS so I advice against it

Answer (score 2):

Discord.py is no longer maintained to work on user accounts, so given the recent updates in the user api, it is no longer the ideal framework which selfbots should be written in.

There are a number of selfbot api libs out there, but the best one that's written in python is this: https://github.com/Merubokkusu/Discord-S.C.U.M

P.S. selfbotting against tos - so be careful (respect rate limits and don't act like a bot)

Answer (score 0):

As Wright has commented, this is against discord's ToS. If you get caught using a selfbot, your account will be banned. However, if you still REALLY want to do this, what you need to do is add/replace `bot.run('email', 'password')` to the bottom of your bot, or `client.run('email', 'password')` to the bottom depending on how your bot is programmed.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My only purpose is to fetch info like *online users* on any server even if not admin. Slack does provide this option.